# The intersection of the zero set of a polynomial and torus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I cannot understand the following statement when learning Floquet transform in the book *Introduction to Quantum Graphs* (More specifically, Theorem 4.5.2) and seeking for a proof or sources to solidify my knowledge in complex analysis.

Let $f$ be a finite Laurent sum on $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{T}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus. If $Z(f) \cap\mathbb{T}^n$ has positive measure on $\mathbb{T}^n$, then $f = 0$.

My backgound knowledge is just a one-semester complex analysis course, but I found that after Floquet transform, we usually deal with functions on $\mathbb{T}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n \setminus \{0\}$. Hence, if there is any recomented textbook for complex analysis (especially for Floquet theory), I am also happy to know!

Comment: Note that there is a significant difference in notation between quotients, which are denoted by $A/B$, and set theoretical difference, which is denoted by $A \setminus B$. As $\mathbb C^n / \{0\} = \mathbb C^n$, I suspect you actually mean set difference $\mathbb C^n \setminus \{0\}$, i.e. all points but the zero point?

Comment: @red_trumpet Oh my bad. Yes, I mean the set difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about Floquet theory but here is a proof of your statement :

First of all, notice that we can write $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{x_1^{m_1}\cdots x_n^{m_n}}$ where the $m_k$ are large enough so $g$ is a polynomial. We have in this case that $Z(f) = Z(g)$ in $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ thus it is enough to prove it for polynomials. Let us prove it by induction on the total degree of $f$ that we assume to be a polynomial.

$*$ If $d = 0$, then $f$ is constant so $Z(f) \cap \mathbb{T}^n = \emptyset$ or $\mathbb{T}^n$ in function of if $f = 0$ or not, which proves the case $d = 0$.

$*$ If $d > 1$, then the differential $df$ of $f$ is non identically zero. It implies that there exists $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} \neq 0$. By induction, $Z\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\right) \cap \mathbb{T}^n$ has zero measure in $\mathbb{T}^n$ so a fortiori, $A = \{x \in \mathbb{T}^n|df(x) = 0\} \subset Z\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\right) \cap \mathbb{T}^n$ has zero measure in $\mathbb{T}^n$.

Now, consider $B = (Z(f) \cap \mathbb{T}^n)\backslash A$ and $x \in B$. In particular, $x$ is in the torus $\mathbb{T}^n = (\mathbb{S}^1)^n$ and for all $z \in \mathbb{S}^1$, $T_z\mathbb{S}^1 = \mathrm{Span}_\mathbb{R}(iz)$ so we deduce that $T_x\mathbb{T}^n = \prod_{k = 1}^n T_{x_k}\mathbb{S}^1 = \mathrm{Span}_\mathbb{R}(ix_1,\ldots,ix_n)$. Notice that $\mathbb{C}^n = T_x\mathbb{T}^n \oplus iT_x\mathbb{T}^n$ and since $f$ is holomorphic, $df(x)$ is $\mathbb{C}$-linear. The decomposition $\mathbb{C}^n = T_x\mathbb{T}^n \oplus iT_x\mathbb{T}^n$ implies that if $df(x)_{|T_x\mathbb{T}^n}$ vanishes, then $df(x)$ vanishes too.

By contraposition, $x \in B \Rightarrow df(x) \neq 0 \Rightarrow df(x)_{|T_x\mathbb{T}^n} \neq 0$ and by $\mathbb{C}$-linearity, this linear map is surjective onto $\mathbb{C}$, which means that $f : \mathbb{T}^n\backslash A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a submersion thus $B$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{T}^n\backslash A$ of dimension $n - 1$, hence it has measure zero in $\mathbb{T}^n$. We deduce that $Z(f) \cap \mathbb{T}^n \subset A \cup B$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{T}^n$.

Notice that a stronger result exists : if $f$ is a non zero Laurent polynomial, then
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}^n} \ln(|f(x)|) \, dx < +\infty
$$
which is crucial to define the Ronkin function for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_(mathematics).

Comment: I really have to pick up my memory for complex analysis of several variables but still thank you very much!